# How to call the intent from Fulfilment (cloud function for firebase)?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I am developing POC on Dialogflow. I want to call the Intent from the cloud functions written in fulfillment.

I have a function

```
function description(agent){

}
```

I have mapped this function to intent through

```
intentMap.set('DescIntent', description);
```

I have if - else if loop inside the description function and each condition statement ends by asking a question to the user, the answer to these questions are either 'yes' or 'NO'. 
I can create 1 yes and 1 NO followup intents. but how can I map this to my function?

I.e How can I distinguish the response got from the user either it is for my if condition or to my else if condition ?

I would be so glad if I got the example how can I do this.

Since I am new to this topic, correct me if I am following wrong methodology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each Intent in Dialogflow handles a single thing *that the user has said*.

Your Intent Handler (`description()` in your example) is responsible for handling that one thing they said, and then returning something to the user in reply.

In what you describe, each Followup Intent, therefore, would be a different Intent sent to you. You can either map each to a different function, or have the one function check the name of the Intent and handle it accordingly.

You generally don't have a loop inside the function that is sending messages to the user. Nothing is sent back to the user until the function completes. You may have some if/else statements that determine the reply based on what the user has said this round, plus what you may be remembering from what they said in the past, but that isn't what you've described here.

If you are asking different questions in `description()` based on the input, and you need to react to those questions later in the conversation, you can do one of two things:

1. Set a different [Context](https://dialogflow.com/docs/contexts) for each question asked. This will let you create a different Intent for each yes/no response to the question and a different function to handle each questions reply. You would set the Context you want to match as an Input Context.
2. You can create a Context and set a parameter in the Context to the value for the question you asked. Then, in the Intent handler for the user's yes/no, you can get the parameter from the Context to see what question you asked and act accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the Quick response. But My requirement is consider I have 3 database collections namely col1, col2, col3 . when the user come and say I need 'Jasmine' my function will first search for jasmine in col1 and asks the further question like would you want to know about the discount ? if it is not in col 1 then it will search in col2 and ask the appropriate question . Same way if it is not in col2 then it will move to col3 and ask the question. If it is not in all the 3 collections then it will add jasmine not available to the conversation.

Comment: So all these 3 questions has the answer either YES/ NO . Based on the user response it needs to go to the some other functions and proceed. So How can I do this ? Can you please help me with this

Comment: Updated my answer. If you're still not sure how this would work, update your question to give a code example of what you're trying to do and why the approach doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Yes Something I got the point , but I would be glad if I got any example please. I updated my question.